# Если я получил недокументированные исходники на языке python, то как узнать какую версию интерпретатора python использовать для их запуска?

Tags: python

За исключением варианта - "Спросить у автора"

Comment: Методом проб и ошибок.

Comment: Если `print` без скобок, то это версия 2.x, а в остальном не только ведь версию питона угадать надо будет, но ещё и версии подключаемых библиотек, а это может быть тот ещё квест.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html Если есть несовместимости с python3 - эта утилита покажет.

Так же `pylint` с опцией `--py3k`.

Аналогично для зависимостей определенных в requirements.txt используйте https://pypi.org/project/caniusepython3/

Если ни одна из них не показывает несовместимостей - очень вероятно, что код написан на python3.